# Creating a textNode, but using character entity references

Tags: htmlspecialchars, createtextnode

I tried creating a text node with character entity references. (In JavaScript)  I was not successful.
Question:  How would I create a text node with special characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the unicode value notation:
`document.createTextNode("\uf012");`